# How to redirect the output of script in rc.local onto screen?

Tags: rc.local

I have a script in rc.local.
`/root/initstart.sh | tee -a /root/initstart.log`

I need this script to be executed when system startup.
This script needs a very long time to finish.

I want to know if it's working well but on screen I can only see this:

`A start job is running for /etc/rc.d/rc.local ...`

[image: A start job is running for /etc/rc.d/rc.local]

Is there a way to show the script's output on screen when startup?

Comment: Why not just add it as a systemd service?

Comment: It was an old project so I didn't think about it yet. I will give it a try.

Comment: You can also direct logging through the following configuration options:
`StandardOutput=journal+console`
`StandardError=journal+console`